# what does the following rpm "%prep" step do?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Assuming

```
Source0:        %{gnu_download_url}/coreutils/coreutils-%{version}.tar.gz
Source1:        mk7distro.tar.bz2
Patch0:         hostutils.patch.bz2
```

Can someone tell me what does the following command do in `%prep` section of RPM spec file ?

```
%setup -q -n %{name} -c -a 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [macro that unpacks the sources](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html):

```
the %setup macro is used to unpack the original sources, in preparation for the
build. In its simplest form, the macro is used with no options and gets the name
of the source archive from the source tag specified earlier in the spec file.
```

Comment: so what happens in the command ? Does both `Source0` and `Source1` are uncompressed ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question more precisely, and to provide an updated link, yes, the [%setup command](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s04.html) will uncompress the Source1 tarball, however it will not uncompress the Source0 tarball because of the `-a 1` option specified.  The `-c` option will cause it to extract the tarball to a sub-directory named according to `-n %{name}`, which comes from the "Name:" part of the spec file.

> %setup -q This command changes to the build directory, typically
> /usr/src/redhat/BUILD, and then extracts the source files. This macro
> expects that at least one of the source files will create the
> necessary subdirectory under /usr/src/redhat/BUILD. This subdirectory
> should be named with the package name and version, such as
> telnet-1.0.1. If you are not using a compressed tar archive that will
> automatically create the right subdirectory, add the –c option to the
> %setup macro. The –c option creates the subdirectory for extracting
> the sources.
>
> The %setup directive can automatically extract tar, zip, gzip, bzip2,
> pack, compress, and lzh compressed files. The tar-gzip format is most
> widely used, though.

Comment: Since the content pages keep getting changed round:
https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/rpm/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html